# Add CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to Magento 2 curl

Tags: magento2, curl, curl-request

Currently i'm using magento 2 curl framework to connect to rest api like this:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
  ) {
      $this->_curl = $curl; 
  }

private function post(){
      $url = "https://pro.test.com/api/test";
      $params = array("invoice"=>"SOCAG00183235715","method"=>"ups");
      $this->_curl->post($url, $params);
      $response = $this->_curl->getBody();
      return json_decode($response);
  }
```

from the above code, i can add parameter to the post field, the problem is i need to add the array option to curl header, for example if i use basic curl php, the code structure will look like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://pro.test.com/api/test",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "invoice=SOCAG00183235715&method=ups",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "key: 212thisismykey6969"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers = ["Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
"key" => "212thisismykey6969"];
$this->_curl->setOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$this->_curl->setHeaders($headers);
$this->_curl->post($url,$params);
$response = $this->_curl->getBody();
```

For Reference :- check the below link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/gs-curl.html